# What is the word for the "shape" of json requests/responses?

Tags: documentation, json

For example, what would you name a module containing all of the Pydantic models for your FastAPI project? What would you put as a subtitle in your documentation below an example JSON api response? In XML you'd call it a 'schema' but I don't see that word used to describe this in the json world (because there's no schema document which will enforce the shape.)

Comment: I actually think this is not opinion based, he’s asking for a community-agreed term to refer to the schema of a JSON file. There must be a term that can be backed by more documentation and references which should be what the OP is looking for. I think this question is in cat 1: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would still call it a schema. There's even a standard: https://json-schema.org/